# Getting "sslv3 alert handshake failure" when trying to connect to Ansible Tower

Tags: alert, handshake, sslv3

I have a gitlab pipeline connecting to an ansible tower (hosted on prem). Post switching my runner image from Python 3.7 to 3.11 started getting SSL handshake errors

*Starting process........
Getting Ansible host ID.....
Error in main function. Error message:Error in get_host_id(). Error details:Error in get_inv_id(). Error details:HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ansible.ally.corp', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/inventories/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1002)')))*

Python 3.7 still works.

Understand Python 3.10 increased the default security settings of the TLS stack but still clueless on how to get this integration going with Ansible Tower.